# Paginación en Spring Boot y Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tengo en mi página una lista paginada, que me mostrará presupuestos de 10 en 10. Esa lista es la que verá usuario administrador.
En cambio si es un usuario común, me retorna error en la página. ¿Cómo puedo implementar la paginación a la hora de que me retorne los presupuestos del cliente cuya sesión tenga iniciada?

Esta es mi página donde recojo los presupuestos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
    <title>Presupuestos</title>
    <th:block th:insert="~{sections/head.html}"></th:block>
</head>
<body>
    <th:block th:insert="~{sections/header.html}"></th:block>

    <div class="container" >
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title text-center">Presupuestos solicitados</h4>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a th:if="${actual > 1}" th:href="@{'/list/1'}">Inicio</a>
                        <a th:if="${actual > 1}" th:href="@{'/list/' + ${actual - 1}}">Anterior</a>
                        <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, paginasTotales)}">
                            <a th:if="${actual != i}" th:href="@{'/list/' + ${i}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                            <span th:unless="${actual != i}">[[${i}]]</span>
                        </span>
                        <a th:if="${actual < paginasTotales}" th:href="@{'/list/' + ${actual + 1}}">Siguiente</a>
                        <a th:if="${actual < paginasTotales}" th:href="@{'/list/' + ${paginasTotales}}">Final</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table
                        class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">Cliente</th>
                                    <th>Referencia</th>
                                    <th>Detalles</th>
                                    <th>Total</th>
                                    <th>Direcci&oacute;n</th>
                                    <th>Fecha de solicitud</th>
                                    <th>Acciones</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(presupuestos)}" th:each="presupuesto : ${presupuestos }">
                                    <td sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')" th:text="${presupuesto.cliente.nombre}"></td>
                                    <td th:text="${presupuesto.referencia}"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table
                                            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive small"
                                            th:if="${presupuesto.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.ObraNueva'}">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Superficie</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.superficie}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Calidad</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.calidad}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <table
                                            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive small"
                                            th:if="${presupuesto.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.Aseos'}">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Largo</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.largo}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Ancho</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.ancho}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Alto</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.alto}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Precio azulejo (m2)</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.precio_azulejo_m2}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Modif. instalaciones</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.modif_instalacion}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Sanitarios (precio)</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.num_sanitarios}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <table
                                            class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-responsive small"
                                            th:if="${presupuesto.class.name == 'com.institutmarianao.webtitoproyecto.domain.Cocina'}">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Largo</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.largo}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Ancho</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.ancho}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Alto</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.alto}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Precio azulejo (m2)</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.precio_azulejo_m2}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Modif. instalaciones</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.modif_instalacion}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Muebles (m. lineales)</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.mueble_mtr_lineales}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Encimera (m. lineales)</th>
                                                <td th:text="${presupuesto.encimera_mtr_lineales}"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><h4 class="text-center" th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(presupuesto.total)}"></h4></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span th:text="${presupuesto.destinatario}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        <span th:text="${presupuesto.direccion}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        <span th:text="${presupuesto.codigoPostal}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        <span th:text="${presupuesto.municipio}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        <span th:text="${presupuesto.provincia}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        <span th:text="${presupuesto.comunidad}" th:remove="tag"></span><br>
                                        <span th:text="${presupuesto.pais}" th:remove="tag"></span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td th:text="${#dates.format(presupuesto.fecha, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></td>
                                    <td >
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Editar</a>
                                        <a sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')" th:href="@{/list/delete/{id_presupuesto}(id_presupuesto=${presupuesto.id_presupuesto})}" onclick="return confirm('Vas a eliminar este presupuesto. ¿Seguro?');" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Eliminar</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(presupuestos)}">
                                    <td sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')" colspan="8">No hay guardado ning&uacute;n presupuesto a&uacute;n. Puedes hacer uno nuevo <a th:href="@{/shop}">aqu&iacute;</a>.</td>
                                    <td sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')" colspan="6">No hay guardado ning&uacute;n presupuesto a&uacute;n. Puedes hacer uno nuevo <a th:href="@{/shop}">aqu&iacute;</a>.</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-center">
                        N&uacute;mero de presupuestos: <span th:text="${elementos}"></span><br>
                        Presupuestos en la página: <span th:text="${numprep}"></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer text-center">
                    <a th:if="${actual > 1}" th:href="@{'/list/1'}">Inicio</a>
                    <a th:if="${actual > 1}" th:href="@{'/list/' + ${actual - 1}}">Anterior</a>
                    <span th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(1, paginasTotales)}">
                        <a th:if="${actual != i}" th:href="@{'/list/' + ${i}}">[[${i}]]</a>
                        <span th:unless="${actual != i}">[[${i}]]</span>
                    </span>
                    <a th:if="${actual < paginasTotales}" th:href="@{'/list/' + ${actual + 1}}">Siguiente</a>
                    <a th:if="${actual < paginasTotales}" th:href="@{'/list/' + ${paginasTotales}}">Final</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <th:block th:insert="~{sections/footer.html}"></th:block>
</body>
```

Y así es como lo envío a la vista a través del controlador:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({ "presupuesto" })
public class PresupuestoController {

@Autowired
private PresupuestoService presupuestoService;

@Autowired
private ObraNuevaService obraNuevaService;

@Autowired
private ReformaService reformaService;

@Autowired
private AseosService aseosService;

@Autowired
private CocinaService cocinaService;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    
private LocalDate fechas = LocalDate.now();

private String annio = Integer.toString(fechas.getYear());
private String mes = String.format("%02d",fechas.getMonthValue());
private String dia = String.format("%02d",fechas.getDayOfMonth());

private int nuevoPresupuesto = 0;

@GetMapping("/shop")
public String tienda(Model model) {
    ObraNueva obra = new ObraNueva();
    Aseos aseos = new Aseos();
    Cocina cocina = new Cocina();

    model.addAttribute("obranueva", obra);
    model.addAttribute("aseos", aseos);
    model.addAttribute("cocina", cocina);
    return "haztupresupuesto";
}

@GetMapping("/list")
public String vistaList(Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = authentication.getName();
    Cliente iniciado = (Cliente) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
    
    if (authentication != null
            && authentication.getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(a -> a.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER"))) {
        model.addAttribute("presupuestos", presupuestoService.findByCliente(iniciado));
        return "presupuestos";
    } else {
        return "redirect/list/1";
    }
}

@GetMapping("/list/{pagina}")
public String listado(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "pagina") int pagina) {
        
        Page<Presupuesto> page = presupuestoService.findAll(pagina);
        
        List<Presupuesto> presupuestos = page.getContent();
        
        int paginasTotales = page.getTotalPages();
        long elementosTotales = page.getTotalElements();
        ;
        model.addAttribute("actual", pagina);
        model.addAttribute("presupuestos", presupuestos);
        model.addAttribute("numprep", presupuestos.size());
        model.addAttribute("elementos", elementosTotales);
        model.addAttribute("paginasTotales", paginasTotales);
        
    
    return "presupuestos";
}

@GetMapping("/list/delete/{id_presupuesto}")
public String eliminarPresupuesto(@PathVariable long id_presupuesto) {
    presupuestoService.deleteById(id_presupuesto);
    return "redirect:/list";
}

@GetMapping("/finishPresupuesto")
public String finPresupuesto(@ModelAttribute("presupuesto") Presupuesto presupuesto, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = authentication.getName();
    Cliente activo = (Cliente) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

    presupuesto.setCliente(activo);

    return "encargarpresupuesto";
}

@PostMapping("/newObra")
public String nuevaObra(@Valid @ModelAttribute("obranueva") ObraNueva obranueva, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model) {
    
    if(obranueva.getSuperficie() <= 0) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("superficie", null, "Debes introducir un valor y debe ser mayor a 0");
    }

    obranueva.setTotal(obranueva.getSuperficie() * 1100 * obranueva.getCalidad());
    
    nuevoPresupuesto++;
    
    obranueva.setReferencia(ObraNueva.PREFIJO + annio + mes + dia + String.format("%07d",nuevoPresupuesto));

    model.addAttribute("presupuesto", obranueva);

    return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
}

@PostMapping("/newReformaAseo")
public String nuevaReformaAseos(@Valid @ModelAttribute("aseos") Aseos aseos, Model model) {

    aseos.setTotal(
            2 * (aseos.getLargo() + aseos.getAncho()) * aseos.getAlto() + (aseos.getAncho() * aseos.getLargo()) * 50
                    + aseos.getPrecio_azulejo_m2() + (aseos.getAncho() * aseos.getLargo()) * 35
                    + aseos.getNum_sanitarios() + aseos.getModif_instalacion());
    
    nuevoPresupuesto++;
    
    aseos.setReferencia(Aseos.PREFIJO + annio + mes + dia + String.format("%07d",nuevoPresupuesto) + Aseos.SUFIJO);

    model.addAttribute("presupuesto", aseos);

    return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
}

@PostMapping("/newReformaCocina")
public String nuevaReformaCocina(@Valid @ModelAttribute("cocina") Cocina cocina, Model model) {

    cocina.setTotal(2 * (cocina.getLargo() + cocina.getAncho()) * cocina.getAlto()
            + (cocina.getAncho() * cocina.getLargo()) * 50 + cocina.getPrecio_azulejo_m2()
            + (cocina.getAncho() * cocina.getLargo()) * 35 + (cocina.getMueble_mtr_lineales() * 80)
            + (cocina.getEncimera_mtr_lineales() * 150) + cocina.getModif_instalacion());
    
    nuevoPresupuesto++;
    
    cocina.setReferencia(Cocina.PREFIJO + annio + mes + dia + String.format("%07d",nuevoPresupuesto) + Cocina.SUFIJO);

    model.addAttribute("presupuesto", cocina);

    return "redirect:/finishPresupuesto";
}

@PostMapping("/newPresupuesto")
public String nuevoPresupuesto(@ModelAttribute("presupuesto") Presupuesto presupuesto, BindingResult bindingResult,
        Model model, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("presupuesto", presupuesto);
        return "encargarpresupuesto";
    }

    if (presupuesto instanceof ObraNueva) {
        ObraNueva obra = (ObraNueva) presupuesto;
        obraNuevaService.save(obra);
    }

    if (presupuesto instanceof Aseos) {
        Aseos reforma_aseo = (Aseos) presupuesto;
        aseosService.save(reforma_aseo);
        reformaService.save(reforma_aseo);
    }

    if (presupuesto instanceof Cocina) {
        Cocina reforma_cocina = (Cocina) presupuesto;
        cocinaService.save(reforma_cocina);
        reformaService.save(reforma_cocina);
    }

    presupuestoService.save(presupuesto);
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:/list";
}
```

}

Intento enviarle los presupuestos por cliente pero no puedo, me lanza un 500 porque espera la pagina actual, el total de presupuestos en mi bbdd... entonces, ¿cómo podría enviarles los presupuestos solo de ese cliente con paginación?